# Filter Database values according to the login user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

in my application i want to filter data according to the user (not for user level).as example i have a user and when they login to the system i want to view them their own data.how can i do that using codeigniter.i also have  created a session in login controller. and hesder. now i want to filter data from another controller.is it possible?

here my code for session in Login controller

```
 public function user_login_process() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
//$this->load->view('admin_page');
    $this->home();
}else{
$this->load->view('user_site/login_form');
}
} else {
$data = array(
'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
'password' => $this->input->post('password')
);
$result = $this->login_database->login($data);
if ($result == TRUE) {

$email = $this->input->post('email');
$result = $this->login_database->read_user_information($email);
if ($result != false) {
$session_data = array(
'firstname' => $result[0]->firstname,
'email' => $result[0]->email,
    'id' => $result[0]->id,
);
// Add user data in session
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
//$this->load->view('index');
//                    $this->home();
                    $this->load->view("user_include/header");
                    $this->load->view('user_site/index');
}
} else {
$data = array(
'error_message' => 'Invalid Username or Password'
);
$this->load->view('user_site/login_form', $data);
}
}
}
```

this is the header

```
    <?php
if (isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])) {
$firstname = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['firstname']);
$email = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['email']);
$id = ($this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id']);
} else {
header("location: login");
}
```

now i want to filter data in another controller

```
function get_book(){
  $this->db->select("book.id,book.title");
  $this->db->where("user_id = $id");
  $this->db->from('book');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

when i used the above code to filter data it shows an

> error Undefined variable: id

this is my code for the view.

```
<?php foreach($post as $post){?>
 <tr>

     <td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
     <td><?php echo $post->title ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
 </tr>  
 <?php }

 ?>
```

this is my controller

```
    public function index(){ 
$data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_book(); 
 $this->load->view('user_include/header');
 $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store `id` in your session variable. For getting this you use

```
  $id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
```

Model

```
function get_book(){
  $id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];// getting id
  $this->db->select('id,title');
  $this->db->where('user_id', $id);//
  $this->db->from('book');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: when i use your code it shows error called 
"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "
and previous error was fixed

and please hepl me to fixed it


 <?php foreach($post as $post){?>
     <tr>
 <td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
<td><?php echo $post->title ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
        
 </tr>  
     <?php }
     
     ?>

Comment: You have to shoe us where you call `get_book` function from controller and where use for `foreach` loop

Comment: yes that problem is solved. this is my controller

** public function index(){  
        
 $data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_book();
//        $this->load->view('user_include/header');
        $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data);
 }**

Comment: Please write a new question for this along with your code and error. And don't paste you code in comment it nor able to understand. ANd colose this question for attecting it

Comment: check updated answer and make sure you are call model file in consrtuctor

Comment: and use `$this->db->last_query();` to print your query

Comment: Object of class book_model could not be converted to string

Filename: models/book_model.php

Line Number: 19

Comment: `print_r( $id)`; in model and paste the value of it and `print_r($_SESSION)`;

Comment: i coulden't unserstant what u say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87563/discussion-between-saty-and-ashik).